# Sonar: Replace this use of "unique_ptr" by a raw pointer or a reference (possibly const)

Tags: c++, reference, unique-ptr

I have the following piece of code for which Sonar is giving the following warning:

> Medium·Code smell·Replace this use of "unique_ptr" by a raw pointer or
> a reference (possibly const).View report

---

```
Result runQuery(const std::string& iQuery,
                const std::unique_ptr<hri::search::n1ql::N1qlClientProxy>& iN1qlClient)
{
    kvclient::N1QLQuery n1qlQuery{iQuery};

    std::vector<std::string> n1qlResult;
    const kvclient::Status&  status = iN1qlClient->query(n1qlQuery, n1qlResult);
    return result;
}
```

---

Should I dereference the pointer and pass it as reference? like for instance

```
Result result = runQuery(iQuery,*iN1qlClient);
```

With runQuery being modified to

```
Result runQuery(const std::string& iQuery, const hri::search::n1ql::N1qlClientProx & iN1qlClient)
```

Is passing a reference to unique pointer really that bad?

Comment: You should pass a unique pointer to a function only if this function needs to deal with ownership. This doesn't seem to be your case.

Comment: I would say yes. Your function says that the caller of the function must have the structure as a `unique_ptr`. What happens when the caller has it as an automatic variable on the stack? Or the caller uses your function with different structures and has a `vector` of it?